# My bundle tracing options not listed in Tracing UI dialog

Tags: eclipse, osgi, eclipse-rcp, osgi-bundle

Each of my bundles has a `.options` file containing a list of trace options for that bundle.

I have recently reorganised the project to be built using features rather than plugins and can no longer select trace options from the UI. The Tracing Preferences Dialog only shows platform options.

The new version is based on 2020-3 and the previous version was based on Kepler. I have compared the settings between the two but cannot identify a significant difference.

Can anyone point me to an up-to-date guide to enabling tracing in RCP apps?

Previously, only my bundle options were shown:

[image]

Now, only eclipse options are shown:

[image]

Comment: The tracing dialog looks for the `org.eclipse.ui.trace.traceComponents` extension point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @greg-449 said in his comment, adding the extension `org.eclipse.ui.trace.traceComponents` solved the problem. I added it to my core bundle and set it to enable all my bundles.

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.trace.traceComponents">
      <component
            id="com.acme.atf.app.component1"
            label="ATF">
         <bundle
               name="com.acme.atf.*"></bundle>
      </component>
   </extension>
```

I can't explain why I only have to do this since I converted from a bundle-based configuration to a feature-based configuration. Previously, my trace points were listed without adding the extension point.